# htaccess Redirect to Child Directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to 301 redirect to a child directory using .htaccess i.e.

```
Redirect 301 /parent http://example.com/parent/child/
```

Unfortunately this results in a redirect loop i.e.

```
/parent/child/child/child/child/etc.
```

Please could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive will match and redirect everything that starts with `/parent`. You need to use [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) to only redirect this specific folder:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/parent/?$ http://example.com/parent/child/
```

The same, but using **mod_rewrite**:

```
RewriteRule ^parent/?$ http://example.com/parent/child/ [R=301,L]
```

**NOTES:**
Place it in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required.